# using \SI of siunitx as value in \TextField of hyperref to format number in specific locale

Tags: hyperref, siunitx

I want to use `\SI` as `value` in `\TextField`. The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = DE}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        \TextField[value={\SI{5.5}{}}]{\SI{5.5}{}}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

produces the output

[image]

Why is the input decimal marker ("point" or "dot") not being replaced with the locale's output decimal marker ("comma") in `\TextField`, and how do I solve this?

Comment: That won't work, \SI is not expandable.

Comment: Aside: Even though it won't solve the main issue at hand, do consider replacing `\SI{5.5}{}` with `\num{5.5}`.

Comment: I suppose a quick fix -- a hack, really, not a real solution -- would be to write `\TextField[value={\num{5,5}}]{\num{5.5}}`, i.e., to use a comma as the *input* decimal marker.

Comment: @Mico well this works, but then why not write directly `value={5,5}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for the hint that it won't work. So one part of the question is "Why does it not work?" and the answer is "Because \SI is not expandable", but that doesn't tell me anything. I will try to look into the expanding-concept when I find some time for that.